# Gridview has empty data after assigning datatable which has data?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have data with DataTable. Assiged to gridview , but gridview has 0 row after assign.

```
         Dim mKeywordSearch As New KeywordSearch
         Dim dtExcel As DataTable
         dtExcel = mKeywordSearch.DatabaseKeywordSearch(txtKeyword.Text)
         gvKeywordSearch.DataSource = dtExcel
         gvKeywordSearch.DataBind()
         Dim cnt As Integer = dtExcel.Rows.Count
         cnt = gvKeywordSearch.Rows.Count()
```

.aspx page

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvKeywordSearch" runat="server" Width="100%" 
AutoGenerateColumns="false" Visible="true"></asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your GridView to `AutoGenerateColumns="true"` or define columns as required with `AutoGenerateColumns="false"`

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvKeywordSearch" runat="server" Width="100%" 
AutoGenerateColumns="true" Visible="true"></asp:GridView>
```

Or with `AutoGenerateColumns = "false"`

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvKeywordSearch" runat="server" Width="100%" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="false" Visible="true">
   <Columns>
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="HeaderText1" DataField="FieldName1" ></asp:BoundField>
      <asp:BoundField HeaderText="HeaderText2" DataField="FieldName2" ></asp:BoundField>
      ...
   </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```